# Flexbox content with overflow spills out to the left and becomes unreachable

Tags: html, css

I've got the following flexbox CSS:

```
#penDisplay{
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-evenly;        
        overflow:auto;
        position:absolute;
        top: 15%;
        left:2%;
        width:96%;
        height:65%;
}
#penCard{
        color:#CECECE;
        padding: 15px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        margin-right: 55px;
        width:15%;
        height: 60%;
        background: #2D3344;
        border: 11px solid #004B93;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 53px;
```

and a simple piece of HTML creating 8 of these boxes within.

I am wanting these boxes to be evenly spaced out and justified in the centre when not overflowing, and then when overflowing to scroll out from left to right. My problem is that the overflow spills over to the left as well as the right, and my scrollbar only goes right.

Below is an image of the problem I'm seeing, note the position of the scrollbar and the unreachable item to the left:

[image: error]

EDIT:

My HTML is React but there's nothing really that couldn't be done in basic HTML:

```
function PenCard(props){
    return (
        <div id="penCard">
            <h2><center>Pen {props.value}</center></h2>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
    )
}

export default PenCard
```

.

```
renderCard(i) {
      return (
        <PenCard 
          value={i}
        />
      );
  }
```

.

```
      <div id="penDisplay">
      {this.renderCard(1)}
      {this.renderCard(2)}
      {this.renderCard(3)}
      {this.renderCard(4)}
      {this.renderCard(5)}
      {this.renderCard(6)}
      {this.renderCard(7)}



      </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML

Comment: Share your HTML code for better understanding of the issue

Comment: @BeerusDev added

Comment: @AbinThaha added

Comment: Are you expecting to break the extra div's to the next line or you want a horizontal scroll bar in case if it exceeds the screen width ./

Comment: I want it to stay on one line. But just extend to the right, instead of in both directions.

Comment: But having said that I also want it to be centre aligned when it's not overflowing/scrolling (i.e. when there's 5 or less on the page)

Comment: @Cm1602 Can you explain what does extending to right mean? I mean are you expecting the scrollbar to scroll only to the right?

Comment: @RifkyNiyas Scrolling, sorry my terminology is lazy. In my example image the overflow or scrolling seems to push the "Pen 1" box over to the left, but my scroll bar cannot reach there. I want all my items to be accessible by scrolling, while remaining centre justified.

Comment: Ok, try checking out the answer given below. I think it would solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

`justify-content: space-evenly;` was causing the issue, I have changed it to `justify-content: flex-start;` which resolved the issue.

```css
#penDisplay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 65%;
}
#penCard {
  color: #cecece;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 55px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2d3344;
  border: 11px solid #004b93;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 53px;
}
```

```html
<section id="penDisplay">
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="penCard">
    <h2>value</h2>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
    like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: My problem with this solution though is now when I have less than 5 cards per page I have them squished up to the left of the screen leaving a lot of white space

Comment: Giving `space-between` as value would solve both issues, right ?

Comment: Ah thanks! That does solve it. If I can nit-pick a little further though it now leaves a LOT of space in between each card compared to `space-evenly`. When using 3 cards there is one card justified far left, one far right, and one dead center. Is there a way I can reduce this gap so that they are spaced like `space-evenly` but centre justified like `space-between`?

Comment: You can give a dynamic class with the number of `Cards`, in case if more than 5, use `space-evenly/flex-start`, otherwise, use `space-between`. Like that ?